# list all markers from map Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So I've added 5 markers in my map and i want to get the longitude latitude of each one of markers in foreach using `mymap.eachLayer(function(layer){}`

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([ 50.505, 21.09 ], 5);

L.marker([ 48.856132, 2.351589 ]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("test");
L.marker([ 49.856132, 3.351589 ]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("test");
L.marker([ 50.856132, 4.351589 ]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("test");
L.marker([ 51.856132, 5.351589 ]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("test");
L.marker([ 52.856132, 6.351589 ]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

`eachLayer()` doesn't get all `marker`s, it gets all `layer`s - which might not be the same. Need to check that what it finds is a `marker`

```
mymap.eachLayer(function(layer) {
   if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {   
         alert(layer.getLatLng());
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks peeebeee for the reply actually I want to view all the LatLng in an alert one by one in a foreach so what should I do instead of if()

Comment: Put an alert where I wrote 'your code'. I've altered the answer.

Comment: The map dosen't display any more  and I've got the error in navigator "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: Edit the question, post your code and note which line the error occurs in.

Comment: `instanceof`, not `instanceOf`

Comment: @Matt Noted and fixed